# Backfire (Backbone-Firebase) Collection not Loaded

Tags: backbone.js, firebase, backfire

So basically, I created a Backfire app. As soon as the page is loaded, I am iterating over my Backbone.Firebase.Collection instance.

And then rendering the results onto the page... the problem is that obviously the collection instance does not contain all the data that is on firebase.

So, I put a set-timeout of 1000ms to make it so that the collection has time get its data from Firebase. This way of doing it is terrible... sometimes the data is synced up other times it is not.

How can I have an event be triggered as soon as the "BackFire Collection Model" has its data from firebase?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var myCatalogApp = new CatalogApp()
  var catalog = new Catalog()

  setTimeout(function(){myCatalogApp.displayCollection(catalog)},1000);
  //To give catalog time to asynchronously retrieve database entries
  myCatalogApp.initialize()
})

var Catalog = Backbone.Firebase.Collection.extend({
  model: Item,
  firebase: "https://mycatalogmaker.firebaseIO.com/items"
});
```

All of my problems would be solved if Backfire would let me do a fetch method... but they have it disabled for Backfire objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var myCatalogApp = new CatalogApp()
  var catalog = new Catalog();

  catalog.bind('sync', function(){myCatalogApp.displayCollection(catalog);});

  myCatalogApp.initialize();
})
```

Comment: :( didnt work. Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'listenTo'

Comment: I also tried `myFirebase.once("value", function(snapshot){ myCatalogApp.displayCollection(catalog)})`

Comment: I have updated my answer, try `catalog.bind('reset'...`

Comment: Just tried it... still no luck :( no error messages, but the catalog is not being updated b4 the iteration runs

Comment: The bind event never gets triggered. Basically, the displayCollection method never runs when I use the implementation you specified

Comment: Try `sync` instead of `reset`

Comment: is there a way for me to give you plus points? because I really really appreciated your help!

Comment: you are welcome, just vote up the answer and I will get 10 rep, that's the max you can do :)

Comment: I am unfortunately new, and unable to upvote it. I will upvote it as soon as I have sufficient reputation. ty sir!